# Spring Security Oauth2 SSO with Zuul Proxy

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I'm modifying the [oauth2-vanilla](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2-vanilla) sample from [Springs excellent security tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/). The oauth2-vanilla combines the Zuul Proxy and the UI into a single application. I would like to seperate the Zuul Proxy and the UI. (The Zuul Proxy should act as an API gateway and as a reverse proxy for several UIs).

When accessing the UI via the zuul proxy, it should be able to do SSO based on Oauth2 between the UI and the resource backend.

The oauth2-vanilla looks like this

[image]

Where I want to move to something like this :

[image]

I've removed the UI part from the gateway, and added a zuul route for the ui

```
zuul:
  routes:
    resource:
      url: http://localhost:9000
    user:
      url: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
    ui:
      url: http://localhost:8080
```

I created a new UI webapp containing the UI (Angular stuff) with an `@EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation.

So I'm accessing the UI via http://localhost:8888 (through the zuul proxy).
After authenticating and doing through the UI flow, I can access the /user endpoint that returns me the user. (During debugging, I see that when I access the /user endpoint that I have an HTTP Session with an OAuth2Authentication.

When I access the /resource endpoint however, the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository cannot find a session and is unable to build a context with the OAuth2Authentication.

I've created [a git repository](https://github.com/ddewaele/spring-cloud-seperate-ui-gateway) with the modified sample.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the gateway configuration. 
I've tried changing cookie paths, changing HttpSecurity rules in the proxy but I cannot get it to work.

What I don't understand is why the UI, when accessed through the proxy is able to resolve the `/user` endpoint fine (with an HTTP session and a OAuth2Authentication), but it is unable to access the `/resource` endpoint.

Also, as the UI is now running in the `/ui` context, it seems that I need to have the following code in the gateway for it to load up the angular css / js files.

```
.antMatchers("/ui/index.html", "/ui/home.html", "ui/css/**", "/ui/js/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

It also doesn't seem right that I need to prefix it with the zuul ui route.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does your UI have `@EnableOAUth2Sso`? I would have thought it was more natural (given you have that annotation already on the gateway) to treat it as a resource server (`@EnableResourceServer`). I think that's the conclusion we came to on gitter as well.

Comment: Regarding "/resource": Can the problem be that you aren't including "spring-cloud-starter-security". Which, as I understood, performs the actual matching between session and access-token, and forwards the access-token based on the browsers sessions-ID. I know I had this problem before.

Comment: I think the gateway (zuul) does the matching. Based on the sessonId that the browser sends through the cookie the gateway can find the corresponding access token en pass that on the resource.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you mange to make this work at the end? One question I am not clear about, if zuul has the sso then how each client can use a different client-id/secret?

Comment: @DaveSyer did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get the @EnableOauthSso to work.  Instead, I annotated as an @EnableResourceServer and created a security config for Zuul.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_API")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```